# Remove title bar above chart in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, charts

Hello guys in Stackoverflow, I have a problem, I am trying to remove the top title bar in the chart from Chart.js but it never goes away even though I tried all the common methods to remove it

note:
I am using Chart.js v4.4.2

[Illustrative image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ag65E.png)

```
    <script>
        var ctx = document.getElementById('studentChart').getContext('2d');
        var studentChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: [<?php echo implode(',', range(1, 31)); ?>],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Male',
                    data: [<?php echo implode(',', $analyticsData['maleStudents']); ?>],
                    backgroundColor: 'rgb(54 162 235 / 5%)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    fill: true,
                }, {
                    label: 'Female',
                    data: [<?php echo implode(',', $analyticsData['femaleStudents']); ?>],
                    backgroundColor: 'rgb(255 99 132 / 5%)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    fill: true,
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true,
                            min: 0
                        }
                    }]
                },
                legend: {
                    display: true,
                    labels: {
                        generateLabels: function(chart) {
                            return [
                                { text: 'Male', fillStyle: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.1)', strokeStyle: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)' },
                                { text: 'Female', fillStyle: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.1)', strokeStyle: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)' }
                            ];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

I have tried the solutions provided in Stackoverflow and AI answers but to no avail. Can someone help me here please?

```
     options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        min: 0
                    }
                }]
            },
            legend: {
                display: false
            }
        }
```

Comment: Helps if you use the right terminology. By those "titles", seems you mean the "legend labels". Then right there in the data structure, you see many references to legend. ... What exactly have you tried before coming here? I mean just looking at it, you could try setting the text attributes of the legend to empty strings. You wouldnt need AI to guess that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the options settings, change legend display to false. Please let me know if this works:

```
   options: {
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                display: false,
            
        },
```

Comment: Thank you, it actually works.
I was able to find the solution and share it so everyone can benefit

Thank you again for your response and help